# Plot all columns from a data.frame in a subplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

as the title suggest, I want to plot all columns from my data.frame, but I want to do it in a generic way. All my columns are factor.
Here is my code so far:

```
nums <- sapply(train_dataset, is.factor) #Select factor columns
factor_columns <- train_dataset[ , nums]

plotList <- list()
for (i in c(1:NCOL(factor_columns))){
  name = names(factor_columns)[i]
  p <- ggplot(data = factor_columns) +  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = name))
  plotList[[i]] <- p
}
multiplot(plotList, cols = 3)
```

where multiplot function came from here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

And my dataset came from Kaggle (house pricing prediction): https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

What I get from my code is the image below, which appears to be the last column badly represented.
[image: Output]

This would be the last column well represented:
[image]

EDIT:
Using gridExtra as @LAP suggest also doesn't give me a good result. I use this instead of multiplot.

```
nCol <- floor(sqrt(length(plotList)))
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plotList, ncol=nCol))
```

but what I get is this:
[image]
Again, SaleCondition is the only thing printed and not very well.
PD: I also tried cowplot, same result.

Comment: I would add additional `SaleCondition` column to original  dataset and plot everything in one graph.

Comment: The package `gridExtra` might also help.

Comment: Hi @PoGibas `SaleCondition` is already in the dataset, what I mean is that when I try to do subplot my data, all I have is the last column which is 'SaleCondition`. I cannot plot it all in one graph beacuse I'm want to plot bars.

@LAP I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tidyr you can do something like the following:

```
factor_columns %>% 
  gather(factor, level) %>%
  ggplot(aes(level)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~factor, scales = "free_x")
```